# JQuery can't access inline variables

Tags: jquery

My code is trying get an image url from a repeater and set the background of a div with the image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#box3").css('background-image', 'url("<%# Container.ThumbnailImage %>")');
  $("#box3").css('background-color', '#eee');
});
</script>
```

When I view the HTML source I see this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#box3").css('background-image', 'url("/images/thumb/a3color-printer.JPG")');
       $("#box3").css('background-color', '#eee');
   });
   </script>
```

But the image is not displayed, the background, however is set to #eee. When I check the source using FireBug, it says this

```
<div id="box3" style="background-image: url(""); background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
```

Please help...

90R3

Comment: And when you look at the `Network` tab in FireBug do you see a request for the `a3color-printer.JPG` image being sent? What does the server respond to it? If your application is hosted in a virtual directory in IIS, wouldn't the correct url for this image be `/appname/images/thumb/a3color-printer.JPG`?

Comment: What version of jQuery and what browser (include version) are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

1. try to remove to quotation mark inside url: `url("<%# Container.ThumbnailImage %>")` -> `url(<%# Container.ThumbnailImage %>)`
2. check if `/images/thumb/a3color-printer.JPG` is accessible from server using browser
3. watch the network panel of firebug and see if the request to `/images/thumb/a3color-printer.JPG` is correctly returned (should be 200OK)